# How best to use pandas.DataFrame.pivot?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to translate a dataframe from rows of key, value to a table with keys as the columns and values as cells. For example:

Input dataframe with key, value:

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame([['TIME', 'VAL1', 'VAL2', 'VAL3', 
                       'TIME', 'VAL1', 'VAL2', 'VAL3'],
                      ["00:00:01",1,2,3,"00:00:02", 1,2,3]]).T

    0       1
0   TIME    00:00:01
1   VAL1    1
2   VAL2    2
3   VAL3    3
4   TIME    00:00:02
5   VAL1    1
6   VAL2    2
7   VAL3    3
```

I want it to look like:

```
TIME      VAL1 VAL2 VAL3
00:00:01  1    2    3
00:00:02  1    2    3
```

I can almost get what I want with pivot:

```
>>>df.pivot(columns=0, values=1)
    TIME        VAL1    VAL2    VAL3
0   00:00:01    None    None    None
1   None        1       None    None
2   None        None    2       None
3   None        None    None    3
4   00:00:02    None    None    None
5   None        1       None    None
6   None        None    2       None
7   None        None    None    3
```

And I can merge the rows to get what I want:

```
>>> df.pivot(columns=0, values=1).ffill().drop_duplicates(subset='TIME',
                                                          keep='last').set_index('TIME')
TIME      VAL1 VAL2 VAL3
00:00:01  1    2    3
00:00:02  1    2    3
```

But this seems like a rather awkward way to do it that would waste a lot of memory for a large data set. Is there a simpler method?

I tired looking at `pd.DataFrame.from_items()` and `pd.DataFrame.from_records()` but was not having success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an "ID" variable that indicates which rows go together.  In your desired output, you are implicitly assuming that every block of 4 rows should become a single row, but pandas won't assume that, because in general pivoting should be able to group together nonconsecutive rows.  Each set of rows that you want to become a single row in the new DataFrame must have some shared value.

If your data really is just chunks of four rows, you can create the ID variable like this:

```
df['ID'] = np.arange(len(df))//4
```

You can see that the ID variable now marks which rows should be grouped:

```
>>> df
      0         1  ID
0  TIME  00:00:01   0
1  VAL1         1   0
2  VAL2         2   0
3  VAL3         3   0
4  TIME  00:00:02   1
5  VAL1         1   1
6  VAL2         2   1
7  VAL3         3   1
```

Then use this new column as the "index" of the pivot.

```
>>> df.pivot(index="ID", columns=0, values=1)
0       TIME VAL1 VAL2 VAL3
ID                         
0   00:00:01    1    2    3
1   00:00:02    1    2    3
```

Comment: Hmm I think I now understand how this pivot function is supposed to work.   Does pivot create a new copy of the data in memory?

Comment: @Kyle: Yes, it does.

Comment: When VALx is not a fixed number of rows but varies between TIME blocks, use this instead: `df['ID'] = (df.index=="TIME").cumsum()`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this:

```
In [65]: df
Out[65]: 
      0         1
0  TIME  00:00:01
1  VAL1         1
2  VAL2         2
3  VAL3         3
4  TIME  00:00:02
5  VAL1         1
6  VAL2         2
7  VAL3         3

In [66]: newdf = pd.concat([df[df[0] == x].reset_index()[1] for x in df[0].unique()], axis=1)

In [67]: newdf.columns = df[0].unique()

In [68]: newdf
Out[68]: 
       TIME VAL1 VAL2 VAL3
0  00:00:01    1    2    3
1  00:00:02    1    2    3
```

Comment: Interesting idea. Basically iterating through the unique values of the key column, selecting those, and concating the columns together?

Comment: @Kyle Yes, indeed!